# How to resolve the error - No module named 'src'?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, python-import, jupyter-lab

I am using Jupyter Lab through Anaconda and have made an environment for my class. I am trying to import LogTime through the following code:

> from src.utils.general import LogTime

But I am getting an error which says "No module found named src." What shall I do to get rid off this error and move ahead with the code. Also, I am getting similar errors with:

> from stationary_utils import check_unit_root
>
> "No module found named stationary_utils."
>
> from target_transformations import DetrendingTransformer
>
> "No module found named target_transformation."

All help will be appreciated. Thanks!

I expected the code to run smoothly and import all the necessary packages.

Comment: Showing us where those modules are actually located would be a good start.